Is it possible to update nested field in MongoDb with findOne?
I tried to setup the query like this:
const dbRecord = await SomeModel.findById(id);
if (newVal !== dbRecord.someArray.oldValue) {
  dbRecord.someArray.oldValue = newValue;
  dbRecord.someArray.updateArray.push(new Date())
}
// ...setting some more properties here

dbRecord.save()

Not sure if it's inherently wrong, but it is saving all properties, except the nested ones.
I am running "mongoose": "6.12.8",
Thanks to @cmgchess
doc.mixed.type = 'changed';
doc.markModified('mixed.type');
doc.save() // changes to mixed.type are now persisted


https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#Document.prototype.markModified() tried this?

You can write an answer

I have no idea how @cmgchess managed to guess that  dbRecord.someArray was a mixed type but bravo all the same! It sounds like a contradiction but it would have been useful if you included your schema so that people could see that one of the fields was a mixed type and it will help future users that have the same problem.

@cmgchess pointed me in the right direction.
doc.mixed.type = 'changed';
doc.markModified('mixed.type');
doc.save() // changes to mixed.type are now persisted

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#Document.prototype.markModified()
